# Memory allocation in Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine

I have installed Oracle VirtualBox in my laptop that has 1 GB of RAM.

In VirtualBox, I have created two virtual machines with 4 GB of RAM.

So my question is: How is it possible to allocate amount of RAM that my laptop, i.e. host system, does not have, and also running applications which uses entire memory space in each of VMs.

Please help me to understand this concept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;dr; Paging (aka swap).

Longer answer:

Ignore the VM part for a bit. I can start a normal process and map more memory than a really have. The OS will grant me the requested (large) space in the virtual address space. When it lacks the physical memory to back that up it will page data to the swap partition.

If I can do that with any program I can also do that with a virtual machine emulator, or with a hyper visor.

Note that performance wise this might not be a good idea. However I do not see a reason why it would not work.